# In Google Sheets, how do I make one column's values be another column's but sorted?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Say column A takes the following values (one value corresponds to one cell):

```
Fewfn
Efaewoinfow
Cfnewoa
Egr
Gqw
Kewno
```

I don't have much experience using Sheets and I simply want column B to be column A but sorted, so that when there is a new value added to column A that value is included in sorted column B.

I don't see how this can be done non-programmatically, for an unlimited number of cells in the columns, and would accept any solution.

So column B initially would be:

```
Cfnewoa
Efaewoinfow
Egr
Fewfn
Gqw
Kewno
```

If I add `Foo` to Column A, I would want the columns to be

A:

```
Fewfn
Efaewoinfow
Cfnewoa
Egr
Gqw
Kewno
Foo
```

B:

```
Cfnewoa
Efaewoinfow
Egr
Fewfn
Foo
Gqw
Kewno
```

It would be even better if repeated values in Column A could be represented just once in Column B.

Comment: What have you tried?  Sheets has both the UNIQUE and SORT functions, which should suit your purpose

Comment: All you need is `=SORT(A1:A)` in GS

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I'm new to Excel really and didn't know that sorting a column could be done by entering a formula into one cell, just asked on here as I thought it would be an easy answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=SORT(A:A)
```

[image]

Note that this spills down dynamically. *(the  output size adjusts to adding/removing items from column **A**)*.
Further to remove duplicates, use:

```
=unique(sort(A:A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sort is the clear winner here as suggested in the comment section by **JvdV**. However, if you would like to include more columns in the future here is an alternative solution.

Use the [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function and **order** by column A:

```
=query($A$1:$A$7,"Select A order by A asc")
```

[image: query]

**or even better:**

```
=query($A$1:$A,"Select A where A is not Null order by A asc")
```

so you **don't need** to specify the size of column A.